# Changing StreetView<->Satellite Google Maps Android

Tags: android, view, maps

i wanna switch my GoogleMaps view between StreetView and Satellite via menubutton.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "StreetView");
    menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Satellite");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
        return true;

        case 1 :
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Won't work.. what do i wrong?

Thanks,
prexx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say it doesn't work, we really need more info to try and help you! Does it crash, does it stay on Street/Sat View or just normal map etc, try to give more info and if it crashed post a copy of the logcat.

I think all you are missing is the line:

(EDIT: I just tried it without calling invalidate and it works so it must be the menu button ID's)

```
mapView.invalidate();
```

You need to call this in order for the mapView to refresh itself, so call it every time you change the mapView settings.

---

If that doesnt work then it may be your id's for the buttons arent recognised in your switch so try setting up your menu as an xml file int res/menu/ like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:title="Street View" android:numericShortcut="1" android:id="@+id/mapStreet" ></item>
  <item android:title="Sat View" android:numericShortcut="2" android:id="@+id/mapSat"></item>
</menu>
```

Then modify your code to:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater oMenu = getMenuInflater();
    oMenu.inflate(R.menu.mapsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.mapStreet:
         mapView.setStreetView(true);
         mapView.setSatellite(false);
         mapView.invalidate();
         return true;

    case R.id.mapSat:
         mapView.setSatellite(true);
         mapView.setStreetView(false);
         mapView.invalidate();
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Uff... i postet my question to fast.. your 2nd tip, to set the menu in an other way. i just "Toasted" the --item.getItemId()-- and recognized, that its 0 on both menubuttons.. my fault was here:menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Satellite");   Sorry guys.. :/ and thanks to you kenny

Comment: Setting up your menu with xml will make life easier, because the id's are all registered and if you want to add in an extra buttons its very simple.

Answer (score 6):

Dont use MapView.
Use GoogleMap and do

```
GoogleMap map;
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Comment: 3 years to late, but ty anyways.