# Google maps: change from satellite view to street view

Tags: android, android-maps

I want to to change the google map view from one state to another. Currently the view is satellite view, now I want to change it to street view. I have written as below but it's not changing the view. How do I change the view at run-time?

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing StreetView<->Satellite Google Maps Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471357/changing-streetview-satellite-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that put this line and let me know what happen,

```
mapView.invalidate();
```

In your code you have to do something like,

```
 mapView.setStreetView(true);
 mapView.setSatellite(false);
 mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: @user370305 u opened the link i posted, and pasted code snippet from there. :-( instead u should have +1 my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall** the project from the emulator and again run it.It hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As the [MapView reference](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView%28boolean%29) shows, `setStreetView` does not change the map to street view - it only toggles showing the blue streaks indicating whether street view is **available** or not, on the map position you're currently looking at. I would guess that the easiest way to start street view is to start google's own street view app via `StartActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

**Is depreciated.**

```
try {

  Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll="+my_lat+","+my_lng+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21"));
  streetView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  startActivity(streetView);

} catch ( Exception ex ) {

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Could not launch Goole Street View. Are you sure it's installed? Launching market...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
  Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.street"));
  startActivity(intent);    

}
```

Without the try/catch your app will crash if street view isn't installed.

Answer (score -1):

See this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471792/236732)

```
     mapView.setStreetView(true);
     mapView.setSatellite(false);
     mapView.invalidate();
```