# how to display hybrid view in google mapview

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

As i am working on the mapview in Android,i am able to display the satellite view but not able to display the Hybrid view,

Please suggest how to display hybrid view in map.

Comment: For Hybrid view, do you mean map view (normal view) overlaped with satellite view?  But for me, I can't hide my map view, so `setSatellite(true)` always gives me a Hybrid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changing StreetView<->Satellite Google Maps Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471357/changing-streetview-satellite-google-maps-android)

Please go through the above link.its is very helpful.

Comment: It is in Webview.Please suggest me in mapview.