# Is it possible to display hybrid maps?

Tags: android

I am usin map in my app. I want to show satellite image and roads. Is it possible in android?
If yes, how?

Comment: try reading here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471357/changing-streetview-satellite-google-maps-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471357/changing-streetview-satellite-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer for v2:

The Google Maps Android API offers four types of maps, as well as an option to have no map at all:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types

- **Normal** - Typical road map. Roads, some man-made features, and important natural features such as rivers are shown. Road and feature labels are also visible.
- **Hybrid** - Satellite photograph data with road maps added. Road and feature labels are also visible.
- **Satellite** - Satellite photograph data. Road and feature labels are not visible.
- **Terrain** - Topographic data. The map includes colors, contour lines and labels, and perspective shading. Some roads and labels are also visible.
- **None** - No tiles. The map will be rendered as an empty grid with no tiles loaded.

**Change the Map Type**

To set the type of a map, call the GoogleMap object's setMapType() method, passing one of the type constants defined in GoogleMap. For example:

```
GoogleMap map;
// ...
// Sets the map type
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not show both view together,

```
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

Using this code you can set view of your mapview.

Comment: Adding a comment for future visitors, this is referring to v1, in v2 you CAN have the following types: normal/hybrid/satellite/terrain/none (no tiles) - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types

Answer (score 0):

use `mapView.setSatellite(true);` this is hybrid view but called satellite here,

satellite view only without road names is not available in Google Maps Android SDK