# How to use Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to Load Map

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to use Google Maps JavaScript API v3 in any Android Application. Please some one post some links for direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3), it goes through all the steps in pretty good detail

[How to change Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471357/changing-streetview-satellite-google-maps-android)

Comment: to do that all you have to do is to set the view of the map when you clck on the chosen button (e.g. mapView.setStreetView(true); mapView.setSatellite(false);) i have added another link to the answer which shows you how to add street view, this the exact same for the rest of the views